# Prevent abbreviation of names for anonymous work with biblatex

Tags: biblatex

This is a follow-up to [Abbreviate resolved abbreviations in authors' first names in biblatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/95331/abbreviate-resolved-abbreviations-in-authors-first-names-in-biblatex), where @PLK provided an [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/95378/9077) in which brackets `[]` and characters between them are replaced by a dot `.`

One problem here is that I have entries in my `.bib` file that are anonymous publications, yet we know who the author is. In those cases I fill in the entire name within brackets, as in `[John Lennon]` below. In such cases where the *entire* name is between brackets, no replacement with a dot `.` should take place.

Question: Is there a way to replace brackets with intervening characters with a dot *except* when the entire `author` field contains such a sequence (e.g. `author = J[ohn] Lennon` is replaced by `author = J. Lennon`, but `author = [John Lennon]` remains `author = [John Lennon]`?

Or put differently, can I somehow "protect" the entry `author = [John Lennon]` below from being targeted by the `DeclareSourcemap` command?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style = authoryear-comp]{biblatex}
\DeclareSourcemap{\maps[datatype = bibtex]{\map{\step[fieldsource = author, match = \regexp{\[[^]]+\]}, replace = .]}}}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@BOOK{lennon1970,
    AUTHOR = "J[ohn] Lennon",
    TITLE = "My life with the Beatles",
    YEAR = "1970",
    SORTNAME = "John Lennon"}
@BOOK{lennon1971,
    AUTHOR = "[John Lennon]",
    TITLE = "Moving on",
    YEAR = "1971",
    SORTNAME = "John Lennon"}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

The question [Brackets in biblatex entries](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/101177/brackets-in-biblatex-entries) might also be relevant here.

Comment: `biber` gives errors for me (and doesn't generate output) on your original but `.\[[^]]+\]` wouldn't match a field that only had `[` at the start.

Comment: What about using `author = "{John} {Lennon}"`?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle The MWE compiles fine with ``pdflatex + biber`` in texlive 2014. Also, using ``\regexp{.\[[^]]+\]}`` will reduce the former output ``Lennon, J.`` to ``Lennon, .``.

Comment: @Werner Isn't that equivalent to just writing ``author = "John Lennon"``? It won't, in other words, indicate in the output that I have supplied the name myself. The output should read ``[Lennon, John]``, not ``Lennon, John``.

Comment: @Sverre: Bracing protects, hence the suggestion. What about `author = {[Lennon, John]}`?

Comment: @Werner That would be equivalent to ``author = "[Lennon, John]"``. I've also tried ``"{[Lennon, John]}"``. They are all replaced by a dot as in the MWE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can anchor regexp searches to the beginning of a string by `\A` and to the end by `\Z`, see http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Regular-Expressions .  If your input was encoded as

```
author = {[Lennon, John]}
```

then you simply add a first test

```
\step[fieldsource = author, notmatch = \regexp{\A\[.+\]\Z}, final]
```

to skip fields entirely contained brackets.  This also works with

```
author = {[John Lennon]}
```

but `biber/biblatex` then treats `Lennon]` as the surname and `[John` as the first name and prints

```
Lennon], [John
```

in the bibliography, which is not what you want.  So one needs to process these entries once more splitting on the final space before the surname.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style = authoryear-comp]{biblatex}

\DeclareSourcemap{\maps[datatype = bibtex]{
\map{
  \step[fieldsource = author, notmatch = \regexp{\A\[.+\]\Z}, final]
  \step[fieldsource = author, match = \regexp{\[[^]]+\]}, replace = .]
}
\map{
 \step[fieldsource = author, match = \regexp{\A\[(.+)\s+([^\s]+)\]\Z},
 replace = {[$2, $1]}]}
}}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@BOOK{lennon1970,
    AUTHOR = "J[ohn] Lennon",
    TITLE = "My life with the Beatles",
    YEAR = "1970",
    SORTNAME = "John Lennon"}
@BOOK{lennon1971,
    AUTHOR = "[John Lennon]",
    TITLE = "Moving on",
    YEAR = "1971",
    SORTNAME = "John Lennon"}
@BOOK{lennon1972,
    AUTHOR = "[J. John Lennon]",
    TITLE = "Moving further on",
    YEAR = "1972",
    SORTNAME = "John Lennon"}
@BOOK{aasen1990,
    AUTHOR = "[{\AA}ge {\AA}sen]",
    TITLE = "Mitt liv",
    YEAR = "1990",
    SORTNAME = "{\AA}ge {\AA}sen"}
@BOOK{estevez1990,
    AUTHOR = "[{\'E}milio {\'E}stevez]",
    TITLE = "Hola",
    YEAR = "1990",
    SORTNAME = "{\'E}milio {\'E}stevez"}
@BOOK{aasen1991,
    AUTHOR = "{\AA}[ge] {\AA}sen",
    TITLE = "Mitt liv 2",
    YEAR = "1991",
    SORTNAME = "{\AA}ge {\AA}sen"}
@BOOK{estevez1991,
    AUTHOR = "{\'E}[milio] {\'E}stevez",
    TITLE = "Hola 2",
    YEAR = "1991",
    SORTNAME = "{\'E}milio {\'E}stevez"}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\nocite{*}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I've edited your code to show that it works when names begin with LaTeX macros like ``{\AA}`` and ``{\'E}`` as well (which I suspected it wouldn't, given the regexp ``\A`` and ``\Z``).