# Abbreviating a name in biblatex when first name is missing

Tags: biblatex

This is now a follow-up to [Prevent abbreviation of names for anonymous work with biblatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/212653/prevent-abbreviation-of-names-for-anonymous-work-with-biblatex), itself a follow-up to [Abbreviate resolved abbreviations in authors' first names in biblatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/95331/abbreviate-resolved-abbreviations-in-authors-first-names-in-biblatex).

In short, I need to print the names of the authors as they appear in their own original work. In my `.bib` file, on the other hand, I always supply the missing information about names within brackets. The trick is therefore to delete this extra information in appropriate ways.

Now, using the code from Andrew Swann's [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/212723/9077) to my question, I notice that when I have an entry in my `.bib` file in which the author's first name is missing, yet supplied in brackets, the output prints the author's last name followed by a comma plus white space plus a period, because the code has abbreviated a first name into an empty white space character:

`Lennon, . (1974)`.

The appropriate output would be one that just prints the last name: `Lennon (1974)`. The other names should appear as they do in this MWE.

Any suggestions?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style = authoryear-comp]{biblatex}

\DeclareSourcemap{\maps[datatype = bibtex]{
\map{
  \step[fieldsource = author, notmatch = \regexp{\A\[.+\]\Z}, final]
  \step[fieldsource = author, match = \regexp{\[[^]]+\]}, replace = .]
}
\map{
 \step[fieldsource = author, match = \regexp{\A\[(.+)\s+([^\s]+)\]\Z},
 replace = {[$2, $1]}]}
}}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@BOOK{lennon1970,
    AUTHOR = "J[ohn] Lennon",
    TITLE = "My life with the Beatles",
    YEAR = "1970",
    SORTNAME = "John Lennon"}
@BOOK{lennon1971,
    AUTHOR = "[John Lennon]",
    TITLE = "Moving on",
    YEAR = "1971",
    SORTNAME = "John Lennon"}
@BOOK{lennon1972,
    AUTHOR = "[J. John Lennon]",
    TITLE = "Moving further on",
    YEAR = "1972",
    SORTNAME = "John Lennon"}
@BOOK{lennon1973,
    AUTHOR = "John Lennon",
    TITLE = "Still moving on",
    YEAR = "1973",
    SORTNAME = "John Lennon"}
@BOOK{lennon1974,
    AUTHOR = "[John] Lennon",
    TITLE = "I'm out of here",
    YEAR = "1974",
    SORTNAME = "John Lennon"}
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

**EDIT**

Applying [moewe's suggestion below](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/261083/9077), something goes wrong when there is more than one author with brackets in the `AUTHOR` field.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style = authoryear-comp]{biblatex}

\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype = bibtex]{
    \map{
      \step[fieldsource = author, match = \regexp{\A\[(.+)\s+([^\s]+)\]\Z}, replace = {[$2, $1]}]
    }
    \map{
      \step[fieldsource = author, match = \regexp{(\w+)\[(.+)\]}, replace ={$1.}]
    }
    \map{
      \step[fieldsource = author, notmatch = \regexp{\A\[(.+)\]\Z}, final]
      \step[fieldsource = author, match = \regexp{(\A|\,\s)\[(.+)\]}, replace = {}]
    }
  }
}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@BOOK{lennon1970,
    AUTHOR = "J[ohn] Lennon",
    TITLE = "My life with the Beatles",
    YEAR = "1970",
    SORTNAME = "John Lennon"}
@BOOK{lennon1971,
    AUTHOR = "[John Lennon]",
    TITLE = "Moving on",
    YEAR = "1971",
    SORTNAME = "John Lennon"}
@BOOK{lennon1972,
    AUTHOR = "[J. John Lennon]",
    TITLE = "Moving further on",
    YEAR = "1972",
    SORTNAME = "John Lennon"}
@BOOK{lennon1973,
    AUTHOR = "John Lennon",
    TITLE = "Still moving on",
    YEAR = "1973",
    SORTNAME = "John Lennon"}
@BOOK{lennon1974,
    AUTHOR = "[John] Lennon",
    TITLE = "I'm out of here",
    YEAR = "1974",
    SORTNAME = "John Lennon"}
@BOOK{lennon1975,
    AUTHOR = "Lennon, [John]",
    TITLE = "I'm out of here",
    YEAR = "1975",
    SORTNAME = "John Lennon"}
@BOOK{beatles1970,
    AUTHOR = "John W[inston] Lennon and J[ames] Paul McCartney",
    TITLE = "Let it be",
    YEAR = "1970"}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These regex trickeries can be quite complicated and the solution here might well have its drawbacks, but here goes ...

```
\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype = bibtex]{
    \map{
      \step[fieldsource = author, match = \regexp{\A\[(.+)\s+([^\s]+)\]\Z}, replace = {[$2, $1]}]
    }
    \map{
      \step[fieldsource = author, match = \regexp{(\w+)\[(.+?)\]}, replace ={$1.}]
    }
    \map{
      \step[fieldsource = author, notmatch = \regexp{\A\[(.+)\]\Z}, final]
      \step[fieldsource = author, match = \regexp{(\A|\,\s)\[(.+?)\]}, replace = {$1}]
    }
  }
}
```

The first map is taken verbosely from the MWE and hence Andrew Swann's answer.
The second map transforms pairs of brackets immediately following a word character (i.e. a letter) into an abbreviation dot.
Finally, the third part deletes an entire first name if wrapped in brackets (`[John] Lennon` and `Lennon, [John]` both match and are transformed to `Lennon`).

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style = authoryear-comp]{biblatex}

\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype = bibtex]{
    \map{
      \step[fieldsource = author, match = \regexp{\A\[(.+)\s+([^\s]+)\]\Z}, replace = {[$2, $1]}]
    }
    \map{
      \step[fieldsource = author, match = \regexp{(\w+)\[(.+?)\]}, replace ={$1.}]
    }
    \map{
      \step[fieldsource = author, notmatch = \regexp{\A\[(.+)\]\Z}, final]
      \step[fieldsource = author, match = \regexp{(\A|\,\s)\[(.+?)\]}, replace = {$1}]
    }
  }
}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@BOOK{lennon1970,
    AUTHOR = "J[ohn] Lennon",
    TITLE = "My life with the Beatles",
    YEAR = "1970",
    SORTNAME = "John Lennon"}
@BOOK{lennon1971,
    AUTHOR = "[John Lennon]",
    TITLE = "Moving on",
    YEAR = "1971",
    SORTNAME = "John Lennon"}
@BOOK{lennon1972,
    AUTHOR = "[J. John Lennon]",
    TITLE = "Moving further on",
    YEAR = "1972",
    SORTNAME = "John Lennon"}
@BOOK{lennon1973,
    AUTHOR = "John Lennon",
    TITLE = "Still moving on",
    YEAR = "1973",
    SORTNAME = "John Lennon"}
@BOOK{lennon1974,
    AUTHOR = "[John] Lennon",
    TITLE = "I'm out of here",
    YEAR = "1974",
    SORTNAME = "John Lennon"}
@BOOK{lennon1975,
    AUTHOR = "Lennon, [John]",
    TITLE = "I'm out of here",
    YEAR = "1975",
    SORTNAME = "John Lennon"}
@BOOK{beatles1970,
    AUTHOR = "John W[inston] Lennon and J[ames] Paul McCartney",
    TITLE = "Let it be",
    YEAR = "1970"}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! But I think you misunderstood parts of my question. For anonymous work, in which the entire name is put between brackets in my `.bib` file, I do _not_ want the brackets removed. In my example, then, I only want to fix the `Lennon, . (1974).` entry to `Lennon (1974).` Everything else should stay the way it is. (If you manage to find a solution to this, please just add it to your existing answer, which I think migth be useful on a later occasion as well `:)`)

Comment: @Sverre Indeed, I had misunderstood the question... Try the edited version then, if you will.

Comment: Would you mind adding a short comment on what part of the code does what?

Comment: Actually, something goes wrong when there's more than one author with brackets in their name - see my updated question (in a minute or two).

Comment: @Sverre Of course it does, but that is probably far above my pay grade. The regex is going to be much more involved, I would think.

Comment: I didn't know there were biblatex problems you couldn't solve :)

Comment: @Sverre OK, that was just a matter of [greediness and laziness](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html), have a look at the new version, please.

Comment: @Sverre I found another corner case where a small modification was necessary (add `$1` in the third map). You may want to try the new solution.

Comment: Sweet! In my actual document, though, I'm left with a comma in the case where the entire first name is within brackets. I'll do some diagnostics to figure out what this code interfers with and open a new question (I'll consider this question solved now).

Comment: @Sverre Yes, I got Biber warnings about something like this as well, but those were safe to ignore since Biber just drops that unnecessary comma.

Comment: I found the culprit. Your code interfers with [this code](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/209951/9077). I'll open a new question about it.

Comment: Follow-up question in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/261105/commas-in-biblatex-entries